# Is it possible to directly call the AWS SDK from a ServiceNow business rule, and can I use it to update an amazon lex slot?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, servicenow, amazon-lex

I have a business rule in SN that translates csv data from a table, turns it into a json object. I need that json object to then be in the format that Amazon Lex requires for slot values. (specific json object structure). With this, I then need to somehow call the aws sdk for authentication reasons, so that i can update the lex bot slot. I have tried the following code, but i know it will not work correctly due to the client-side portion of the script.

```
(function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) {

    var AWS = getTopWindow().document.createElement('script');
            AWS.src = 'https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.388.0.min.js';
            g_form.getFormElement().appendChild(AWS);
            AWS.onload = function() {
                    callback();
            };

    gs.includes('CSVtoJSON');
    //this gives access to the object and it's methods / properties
    var csvToJSON = new CSVtoJSON();
    //this runs the function getAttachmentGR
    csvToJSON.getAttachmentGR(sys_id);

})(current, previous);
```

what could i do here to rectify my issue, if possible?